# MySql handling null return values

Tags: mysql, null

I have a simple query as follows:

```
SELECT sum( people) as total
FROM event
WHERE event.id = 4;
```

The event id `4` is not in the table (intentionally) so the query returns `NULL`. How would I modify the query to deal with `NULL` values?

I am trying to use this with a php script so if the id is non existent the php script should fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pull it into PHP if the value of your summed column is null then you have a null...

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
if ($row['total'] === null)
    ...
```

Comment: let me try your solution

Answer (score 1):

You can just do it in PHP.  I have my database classes return false if the query did not select any records.   You can check that a value was returned from your query statement, if there was, you can count the number of rows and make sure they are greater than 0.

Try this in your query..

```
select * from (SELECT sum( people) as total FROM event WHERE 
event.id = 4) as subsel where subsel.total is not null
```

That should make it so it returns no rows.

Comment: if it returns null it still counts as a row so that wont work

Comment: mysqli. What you are doing is returning an empty set in my problem it still returns a row with the value null